webview.getHeight() inside of onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) not working
I need to get webview height of each one of these webviews
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="40dp"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" >

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/wvwText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </ScrollView>

In the code,
        wvwText.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        String unencodedTextHtml = "<html><body>"+some_html+"</body></html>";
        String encodedTextHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedTextHtml.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
        wvwText.loadData(encodedTextHtml, "text/html", "base64");
        wvwText.setOnTouchListener((v, motionEvent) -> extendText(textContainer, questionContainer, optionsContainer));

        wvwText.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
                int y = lin.getHeight();
                Log.d("myapp", "height: "+y);
            }
        });

I can't get the height of the webview. What could be the reason and how to overcome this?

This is a little unclear. What do you mean by not being able to get the vertical size? What do you get instead? Is it crashing? Also, are you trying to get the height of the WebView itself, or its content, the actual page?

I allways get 0. I need to get height of webview with html content.

That's still not clear. If you're looking for the height of the loaded page, WebView has the getContentHeight() method. That's in dp, so you'll have to multiply its return by the current density to get pixel height. If it's still not quite ready after onPageFinished(), you might have to post a VisualStateCallback and wait for that too.

Thank you, @Mike. M.! My problem was only to catch the height of the WebView after html content render. You helped me pointing to getContentHeight().

I ended up placing
view.post(() -> {
Log.d("myapp", view.getHeight() );
});
inside of onPageFinished
